# Remove quotes from quoted string using regex

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, replace

I have a string like

```
FVAL(XXX)="TRUE" AND FVAL(TT)="FALSE"
```

I want to replace all `"TRUE"` and `"FALSE"` by `TRUE` AND `FALSE`.

Now the resultant string should be

```
FVAL(XXX)=TRUE AND FVAL(TT)=FALSE
```

Will the code shown below be upto the mark for this.

```
Regex.Replace("FVAL(XXX)=""TRUE"" AND FVAL(TT)=""FALSE""", "[""]TRUE[""]", "TRUE", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

**Note:** Now I know you guys would say that this is not a constructive question and should be closed, but the reason I asked this is because what I came up with, will have to be written twice once for `TRUE` and once for `FALSE`, which is not the desired result, instead I want the regex to find and replace just once. Also I have to be absolutely sure that my regex would not miss out any pattern. And lastly if you think this is not constructive enough, then please go ahead and close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USe

```
"(TRUE|FALSE)"
```

and replace it by

```
$1
```

In VB.NET this becomes

```
ResultString = Regex.Replace(SubjectString,
    """(TRUE|FALSE)\""", "$1", 
    RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

Let us know if you have any more questions

Comment: Also, [""] is not necessary right? It's equivalent to just ""