# Using regex to remove quote

Tags: java, regex

I saw a [good sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980141/remove-quotes-from-quoted-string-using-regex), but I cannot adapt it for my problem.

I would like to remove *only enclosing field* `"` from a CSV line like :

```
" kkl ";"aa bb D";;12 "AA";;"SSS"-;" gg 12";" vv";"sdqs ";
```

expected result :

```
 kkl ;aa bb D;;12 "AA";;"SSS"-; gg 12; vv;sdqs ;
```

I use Pattern and Matcher tools

Answer (score 5):

This solution assumes that there is no escaped quote `\"` in the quoted string

```
.replaceAll("(?<=^|;)\"([^\"]*?)\"(?=;|$)", "$1")
```

I assume that you also want to strip off the `"` in these case: `"sdfkjhksdf"`, `;;;"dffff"`

Another solution uses possessive quantifier, whose effect relies on the assumption that `"` doesn't appear inside the quoted portion.

```
.replaceAll("(?<=^|;)(?:\"(.*?)\"){1}+(?=;|$)", "$1")
```

Comment: good idea, but result : kkl;aa bb D;;12 "AA";;SSS"-;" gg 12; vv;"sdqs " --> problem remain near SSS (cote is a part of the text, not a delimiter) and last field,

Comment: @cl-r: Do you have any assumption about the strings inside quote? E.g. Will there be escaped quote inside the quoted string? Will there be `;` in the quoted string?

Comment: @nhahtdk I recieved some CSV with comment text inside field like : The new "modelUpper" is now "downOne" and .. - separator are ';' and field delimiter are " (double cote) - am I clear?

Comment: @cl-r: The thing is that without assumption about the input, neither my solution or Jon Lin's solution would work. His solution assumes that `;` never appears inside quoted string. And my solution assumes that `"` never appears inside the quoted string,

Comment: @cl-r nhahtdh is right, the enclosing quotes are usually there because the CSV delimiter is inside an element. So it may work for your example, but not in practice. You're probably better off with a CSV parser, those will get rid of the enclosing quotes when you ask for elements.

Answer (score 2):

Small modification to @nhahtdh's regex in order to keep it from greedily matching outside of a CSV boundary:

```
.replaceAll("(?<=^|;)\"([^;]*)\"(?=;|$)", "$1");
```